# Adding new row after highest Integer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this line of SQL code (Im using MySQL Workbench)

```
INSERT INTO haulrecord(invoiceNumber, TruckUsed, Client, CargoType, 
                       BeginDate, DeliveryDate, Mileage, Notes)
VALUES('203', '1857', '5', 'Batteries', '06/10/2014', '06/10/2014', '51', 'None');
```

I am going to make a stored procedure but want to add it in after the highest invoice number (the next invoice would be number 203)

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using an `auto_increment` field for the invoice number?

Comment: No reason, I am fairly new to SQL (only been doing it about two months) so most of this is new to me

Comment: You get all the functionality by using an `auto_increment` column that you want, the database handles it all perfectly and you don't need to run any queries each time you insert a row. I would suggest you use it in this case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `VALUES`, you use a `SELECT` clause instead:

```
INSERT INTO haulrecord(invoiceNumber, TruckUsed, Client, CargoType, 
                   BeginDate, DeliveryDate, Mileage, Notes)
SELECT MAX(invoiceNumber) + 1, '1857', '5', 'Batteries', '06/10/2014', '06/10/2014', '51', 'None' FROM haulrecord;
```